# GraphQL Query Syntax Validation in Typescript

Tags: graphql-js

How to validate only the syntax of graphQL Query ?

My requirement is --> User wil enter a query in an editor and need to validate whether it is a graphQL valid query or not? Just syntax validation will be enough. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want validator to return boolean value, you can use this workaround:

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

const isValid = query => {
  try {
    gql(query);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

graphql-tag parses query and if it throws an error, you just return false